# PHP object inside duplicated array is being modified

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array, and some of the elements are objects. I want to end up with 2 arrays, one which has had all string values and object properties passed through my esc() function, and one which is the unmodified original.

Given the following code:

```
$raw = $data;
echo $raw['obj']->description; // Prints '< >Test Desc'

array_walk_recursive($data, function (&$item, $key){
   if(is_string($item)) {
      $item = esc($item);
   } elseif(is_object($item)) {
      foreach ($item as $property => $value)  {
          if(is_string($value)) {
              $item->$property = esc($value);
          }
      }
   }
});

echo $data['obj']->description; // Prints '&lt; &gt;Test Desc' - Correct
echo $raw['obj']->description; // Prints '&lt; &gt;Test Desc' - Incorrect
```

I would expect $raw to be entirely unmodified, and $data to have been processed through esc(). This is the case except for object properties. For some reason the object in $raw is also modified, so that the two `echo` lines print different values, why is this?

Comment: Do you have access to implement a new interface on the class? If you do, you could implement an interface from SPL that lets you iterate over the object as if it were an array ;) if you do have access to the class and could implement it, let me know and i will write you one as my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since PHP 5 objects are always pass-by-reference.

you have to "clone" the objects to really copy them.

see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php for details.

Answer (score 1):

Objects are passed by reference in PHP. This means that if you assign an object `$a` to a variable `$b`, both `$a` and `$b` will point to the same object. This explained in more detail in the [Objects and references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) manual page.

You can use the [`clone`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) operator to really make a clone of an object:

```
$b = clone $a;
```

This only works for objects, though, so you must recursively make a copy of your array where you use `clone` for objects.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's under-the-hood pass-object-by-reference is at work here.

In a nutshell, PHP naturally passes objects by reference, and this includes array members. If you want a proof of this, try the following script:

```
<?php $arr = array(new stdClass()); var_dump($arr[0]); $arr2 = $arr; var_dump($arr[0]); ?>
```

The output will be `object(stdClass)[1]` in both cases.

There are a couple of solutions for you to use. You can, for example, make use of the `clone` operator for objects. If you know the structure of the array, this is trivial. If you don't, you'll have an issue, as PHP cannot `clone` the array (and so, you'll need to recursively walk it). All the other solutions include duplicating your object data before editing it.